# Apply binom_test to every row using columns as argument in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to run binom_test of the certain column as the argument on each row. I have done some of the codes and the same error come out as follows:

```
from scipy.stats import binom_test

bi
    Cij     From     To    Count     p
0   156       A      B       61     0.25
1    4        A      C        1     0.25
2    6        A      D        3     0.25
3    3        A      E        2     0.25

bi['bi'] = bi.apply(lambda x: binom_test(bi['Count'], 
                                       bi['Cij'], 
                                       bi['p'], 
                                       alternative= 'greater'), axis=1)
```

But, the error comes out:

```
~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\scipy\stats\morestats.py in binom_test(x, n, p, alternative)
   2412         n = np.int_(n)
   2413     else:
-> 2414         raise ValueError("Incorrect length for x.")
   2415 
   2416     if (p > 1.0) or (p < 0.0):

ValueError: ('Incorrect length for x.', 'occurred at index 0')
```

Another line of code:

```
bi['bi'] = binom_test(x=bi['Count'],n=bi['Cij'],p=bi['p'],alternative='greater')
```

And the error:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1208-824c68319c1b> in <module>
----> 1 bi['bi_1'] = binom_test(x=bi['Count1'],n=bi['Cij'],p=bi['p'],alternative='greater')

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\scipy\stats\morestats.py in binom_test(x, n, p, alternative)
   2412         n = np.int_(n)
   2413     else:
-> 2414         raise ValueError("Incorrect length for x.")
   2415 
   2416     if (p > 1.0) or (p < 0.0):

ValueError: Incorrect length for x.
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you used apply with a lambda, the variable `x` is a row and you need to use that:

```
bi['bi'] = bi.apply(lambda x: binom_test(x['Count'], 
                                        x['Cij'], 
                                        x['p'], 
                                        alternative= 'greater'), axis=1)

bi

    Cij From    To  Count   p   bi
0   156 A   B   61  0.25    0.000072
1   4   A   B   1   0.25    0.683594
2   6   A   B   3   0.25    0.169434
3   3   A   B   2   0.25    0.156250
```